# npm token list giving error

Tags: node.js, npm

I just upgraded the npm using:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

When I do `npm token list` now, I get following error:

> npm ERR! code EAUTHIP
>
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic, Bearer
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/USerName/.npm/_logs/2018-03-28T16_31_29_299Z-debug.log

Following are content of above log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'token',
1 verbose cli   'list' ]
2 info using npm@5.8.0
3 info using node@v6.8.1
4 info token getting list
5 http request → GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/tokens
6 http 401 ← Unauthorized (https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/tokens)
7 verbose stack Error: Unable to authenticate, need: Basic, Bearer
7 verbose stack     at fetch.defaults.catch.then.then.result (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-profile/index.js:373:15)
7 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
8 verbose statusCode 401
9 verbose cwd /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/mongoose-diff-history
10 verbose Darwin 17.4.0
11 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "token" "list"
12 verbose node v6.8.1
13 verbose npm  v5.8.0
14 error code EAUTHIP
15 error Unable to authenticate, need: Basic, Bearer
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What needs to be done to properly authenticate and add token in CLI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was probably going in wrong direction. I did login in cli using

```
npm login
```

and after that I was able to do `npm token list` and other related commands easily, without any issue.

Comment: It seems that when I login at ~/ and run `npm token list`, everything is working well. But when I change the directory, `npm token list` fails

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but my issue wasn't solved until I deleted the `.npmrc` file in my current dir.

Even when I tried to get my user after a succesful `npm login` I got this:

```
$ npm whoami --verbode
npm ERR! code E401
npm verb stack Error: Registry returned 401 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/-/whoami
```

More info at:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16448

Answer (score 0):

If this error in angular project and If you are using TFS then =>
 go to tfs => build=> packages=> select npm => click on generate authentication token button => copy generated text => paste it into your local .npmrc file.

[image]