# npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/"

Tags: node.js, npm, realm

I ran
`npm i @wtw/canvas`
and got this error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://pkgsprodsu3weu.app.pkgs.visualstudio.com/"
```

My .npmrc:

```
@willistowerswatson:registry=https://rcss-willistowerswatson.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Core@Local/npm/registry/
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
//always-auth=true
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/rcss-willistowerswatson/RadarEnterprise/_packaging/RadarEnterprise/npm/registry/:username=VssSessionToken
```

I have already tried:

```
vsts-npm-auth -config C:\Users\wilso224\.npmrc

vsts-npm-auth v0.41.0.0
-----------------------
Already have credentials for https://rcss-willistowerswatson.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Core@Local/npm/registry/
```

This also failed:

```
npm i --registry https://registry.npmjs.org @wtw/canvas
```

result:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@wtw%2fcanvas - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@wtw/canvas@0.1.1' is not in the npm registry.
```

I have already read the following:

[npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732744/npm-err-unable-to-authenticate-need-basic-realm-artifactory-realm)

[npm token list giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539929/npm-token-list-giving-error)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cclassic#set-up-authentication-on-your-dev-box

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/401-when-attempting-to-run-npm-install/928369

Thanks.

EDIT#1
I tried npm login anyway which asked me to set up a new account, etc.  I have been on this job for 3+ years and I don't recall needing to set up an account every time I encounter error of this sort.

Comment: did you try `npm login`

Comment: I got  
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@wtw%2fcanvas - Not found

Comment: you need to reset your npm config, easiest way is to reinstall nodejs (should be super easy using nvm)

Comment: I have to use the same nodejs version as the rest of my team - the nvm would make me pick a different version

Comment: Is this issue directly related to Realm or is it just a npm install/config issue?

Comment: @nick I tried nvm use 12.14.0 and after changing the version from12.14.1 to 12.14.0 I still got the same error

Comment: @jay most likely npm install/config issue

Comment: @fritz6 did you try running this command "npm i @willistowerswatson/canvas"

Answer (score 7):

First run:

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -force
```

and then:

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 1):

If the forced `re-auth` doesn't work, you may need to clean and reinstall `vsts-npm-auth`

These steps worked for me:

1. Uninstall vsts-npm-auth

```
npm uninstall -g vsts-npm-auth
```

2. Clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

3. Delete the `.npmrc` file
4. Reinstall

```
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false
```

Microsoft Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cclassic#reset-vsts-npm-auth